# Highcharts with multiple series from JSON Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am making a bar chart from HighCharts from JSON data which the user generates. The JSON is formatted like this:

```
[{"name":"project1","data":[50291,7410,2013,2013,524,201]},{"name":"project2","data":[1776995,758630,25633,4120054,24521,2045]}]
```

Because the user chooses the projects, this JSON data could also be of 5 projects! I need to be able to dynamically load in series into my highcharts. This is the code which I have now.

```
$(function () {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 0,
                beta: 0,
                depth: 0,
                viewDistance: 25
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Dataset'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [],
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['XA', 'XB', 'XC', 'XD', 'XE', 'XF']
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    };
    $.getJSON('/uploads/test.json', function (list) {
        var newseries = {
            name: '',
            data: []
        };

        $.each(list, function (i, item) {
            newseries.name = item.name;
            newseries.data = item.data;
            options.series.push(newseries);
        });
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


        function showValues() {
            $('#alpha-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
            $('#beta-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
            $('#depth-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.depth);
        }

        // Activate the sliders
        $('#sliders input').on('input change', function () {
            chart.options.chart.options3d[this.id] = this.value;
            showValues();
            chart.redraw(false);
        });

        showValues();
    });
});
```

This works when i only have one project in my chart, but when there are more the chart overwrites itself some way and only shows the last project in the JSON. Could someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: please call console.log(options.series) before this line:var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options) and tell me what you've received ?

Comment: I added the code before the initialization of the chart. no message was shown in my browser, but when I enabled the inspect function of chrome there was one message which says: '[Object, Object, Object]' when I selected three projects!

Comment: I tried: window.alert(console.log(options.series)); and this says undefined! Although in the chart, the values of the last json array are shown..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `name` and `data` nodes of your `newseries` object each time you loop, by declaring them outside of the loop in that way.

I would turn this:

```
$.getJSON('/uploads/test.json', function (list) {
    var newseries = {
        name: '',
        data: []
    };

    $.each(list, function (i, item) {
        newseries.name = item.name;
        newseries.data = item.data;
        options.series.push(newseries);
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Into something more like this:

```
$.getJSON('/uploads/test.json', function (list) {
    var newseries;

    $.each(list, function (i, item) {
        newseries = {};
        newseries.name = item.name;
        newseries.data = item.data;
        options.series.push(newseries);
    });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Although really, in your case, you don't need to loop at all, because your return JSON is already in the proper format for Highcharts.

You can try something like

```
$.getJSON('/uploads/test.json', function (list) {
    options.series = list;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Instead (untested, might need to be tweaked).

Comment: Thank you! Last suggestion works. Very clean code :-)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
$.each(list, function (i, item) {
   if(item.name!=undefined){
       options.series.push({
          name:item.name,
          data:item.data
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: It works! :-D. One thing, it loads the projects which are selected but also a 'Series 1' with no data? This 'Series 1' is not defined in my JSON.

Comment: Jibriggs answer helped me out! Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for helping me out! Have a good day :-)